# Other meaning of ふたたび?

Tags: meaning, translation, manga

I'm reading Cardcaptor Sakura (Clear Card edition), and there is this sentence at the beginning (to explain to the reader who Eriol is), but I can't figure out the second part at all, please help!

「クロウカード」がすべて「さくらカード」に変わり、ふたたびイギリスに帰っていったが…？

My translation is: The Clow Cards were all changed into Sakura Cards, he had returned again to England but...?

I think I might be mistranslating ふたたび.
The reason I think it doesn't make sense as "again" is that Eriol was a transfer student from England, and he returned to England after the cards were changed, but there is no "again" or "second time", he came to Japan, then returned home (plus, "or did he?" with "が" :-) )

Comment: Where is ふたたび in the sentence...?

Comment: Doh! I was so annoyed with it that I skipped it altogether, sorry, fixed now,

Comment: Then it can be understood as a case where the focus of the speaker is (prematurely) shifted to the result of the action from the action itself. After the action, the subject would be in the UK "again".

Comment: Ooooh, I see. Thank you so much for explaining!